# Cannot insert multiple data in a single attempt

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a date and time picker that allows the user to submit multiple sets of data to a database at one go. (as shown in Fig.1)

However when the form is submitted, only the first row's data is successfully inserted into the database. How can I insert the rest of the row's data?

[image]

```
public function createjob() {
    global $database;
    // Don't forget your SQL syntax and good habits:
    // - INSERT INTO table (key, key) VALUES ('value', 'value')
    // - single-quotes around all values
    // - escape all values to prevent SQL injection
    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
  $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= "')";
  if($database->query($sql)) {
    $this->job_post_id = $database->insert_id();
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I've not received any error message. The only sign that there is something wrong is that apart from my first row, the rest of the rows' data are not being inserted @JorgeCampos

Comment: You have 5 rows to insert and code to insert 1 row. Are you running that code 5 times?

Comment: There are two ways to solve your problem since you are using mysql. One use a for and run each insert separately like `insert into table (columns...) values (values); insert into table (columns...) values (values); ....` of course the code will not look like this. Two you can create one insert command with multiple values like: `insert into table (columns...) values (values), (values), (values), (values);` So adjust your code to do one of then.

Comment: @Jorge Campos: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your solution. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: First you need to show what are in your variable `$attributes` add in your code right after the `$attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();` this line: `var_dump($attributes);` And edit you question with the output value

Comment: Okay I've used vardump but I'm still not getting any error